# deploy laravel on server with nginx get a 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am studying laravel now.And I make a blog demo,it works great with MAMP on my mac.
   But when I deploy it on my remote server,it's now work!I can't get anything but a 500 error!
   I search the problem so many times ,I reinstalled my vps and get a new fresh laravel project but the problem is still here.
It's really frustrated!
I will provide my code and my config.
BTW this is the result from the fresh initial laravel project install with composer not my blog demo
OS: centos 6 x64 with php,mysql,nginx
here is my attempts to solve the problem,i will give the pics but cause the lack of reputation the img wont show

as you can see I chmod & chown the files and storage and bootstrap dir :
[image: screen]
chmod -R 775 storage
chown -R www:www

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 www www   4096 May 11 20:42 storage
```

I add the location to nginx config :
[image: screen]

```
location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }

location ~ \.php$ {

    try_files $uri /index.php =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    include fastcgi_params;

    }
```

the fastcgi_pass is right

And I already run there orders 

`php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
composer install
composer clearca`

I opened the debug mode but is looks like laravel doesn't work include debug function
I had checked my nginx access_log and just shows the bingbot and googlebot

`66.249.79.148 - - [12/Jul/2017:17:00:42 +0800] "GET /view/4HGpgbSQ2s8 HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`

then I checked my website.log it just shows the 500 error without any other message

```
153.125.238.239 - - [12/Jul/2017:16:51:42 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
```

I opened chrome console got a message

```
GET http://test.yiqixue.win/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

nothing else
I have solved 430 permission denided with chmod$chown and 404 error with change the fastcgi_pass but I am stuck here,please tell if you have any idea.

Comment: 1) Have you tried using `chmod -R 755 laravel` ? (laravel folder not only storage) 2) can you show us your `.htaccess` file? 3) Have you generated a key? (`php artisan key:generate`)

Comment: Enable `display_errors` in your php.ini and see if you get any errors on the screen. You can also try to add an index.php that just contains `<?= "hello world"` to see if there are something else going on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In some case, my sever did not work in 755 mode so i change it to 777

`chmod -R 777 storage`

After working, i change back to 755

Comment: I noticed a caching issue in Chrome. When I opened in Firefox, Opera or Safari, it worked. Chrome needed the cookies deleted once the permissions where changed.

It's worth noting I wasn't testing on HTTPS and the login form was warning as insecure.

Comment: Thanks @NikK - Freaking caching issue!  I'm like ... I rolled back ALL my nginx configs ... WHY IS THERE STILL A 500?! CACHING!! <3 you!

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled centos and lnmp again,git clone the code.Run composer install,it shows an error that a rich text editor needs to trun on fileinfo function in php.ini,which I already uncommneted in php.ini.So I edit the composer.json remove it.It works!Even though I have no idea what I have done